# How can I get the selected index of a select?

Tags: php, laravel

I am in Laravel 5.7, I will wish to get the index of a select. I have tried this but without success so far.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="company-content">Ville</label>
  <select name="fk_localite" id="" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Selectionner votre ville</option>
  @foreach($localites as $localite)
     <option value="{{$localite->id}}">{{$localite->ville}}
     </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: The view seems correct, please post your controller function code

Comment: Just access via the 'name' of the select, like others inputs.
$request->get('fk_localite');

Comment: @ dparoli: I have edit my first message. Thanks

Comment: @JoaoGRRR: I think the problem is in my Controller no?

Comment: `dd($request->get('fk_localite'))` and see what you get?

Comment: @Iftikhar uddin: I have this "1", Normally I should get id 2.

Comment: It means you're getting the `index` so what's the error now?

Comment: @ Iftikhar uddin: In my dropdownlist when I want to change an item. It is always on the index "1" by default.

Comment: There is another thing with the same name?

Comment: @JoaoGRRR: I have the solution it was in edit.blade.php my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution !

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="company-content">Ville</label>
<select name="fk_localite" id="" class="form-control">
@foreach($localites as $localite)
<option value="{{$localite->id}}" @if($eleves->fk_localite == $localite->id) selected @endif>{{ $localite->ville }}
</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```